# XSLT parsing to get specific structure

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I am trying the parse the below XML and extract the values for each `<row>` element. There could be any number of child `<row>` elements under `<row>`, but I will have the names of the fields under `<row>`. Is there a way to loop and print this in a table using XSLT? Any pointer will be very helpful.

```
<root>
  <dq>    
    <row>
      <rowa>Test 1</rowa>
      <rowb>Test 2</rowb>
    </row>  
    <row>
      <rowa>Test 21</rowa>
      <rowb>Test 22</rowb>
    </row>
   </dq> 
</root>
```

I am trying to get an HTML table, which will be rendered like:

```
Test 1 
Test 2
Test 21 
Test 22
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add desired output based on the input XML. Also, what did you try to do? What is not working? Overall, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: As Yitzhak rightly points out SO users are encouraged to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, a reprex. You can find out how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> Any pointer will be very helpful

This minimal XSLT stylesheet is to get you started:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/dq"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row/child::*">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will produce the following HTML table structure

```html
<table>     
  <tr>  
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>      
    <td>Test 21</td>      
    <td>Test 22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if there is `rowc`? Or `rowd`. Or `rowx`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- Good point! Changed the last template to make it a bit more robust.